# How to create navigation menu in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create navigation menu like this:

[image]

Is this a custom component or it's part of the standard JavaFX platform?

Answer (score 3):

A breadcrumb navigation bar is not part of the JavaFX 2.2 core platform.

I created a [feature request for a breadcrumb control](https://bitbucket.org/JonathanGiles/controlsfx/issue/44/breadcrumb-control) against the [ControlsFX](https://bitbucket.org/JonathanGiles/controlsfx) 3rd party control project.

The image you provided comes from a screen shot of the open source Ensemble application.
Review the [Ensemble source code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html), and see if you can adopt it's code for your application.

Comment: A breadcrumb navigation bar is now a part of ControlsFX library, since 8.0.5